# How to make a function output into a text file with File I/O

Tags: c++, file, io

Now I have a `void` function named `displayAllCars(Cars)`. I would like to display everything in this function to a text file. Below is my code but it doesn't work.

```
void displayAllCars(vector<Vehicle*>& cars)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 <<". ";
        cars[i]->display();
        cout << endl;
    }
}



        ofstream salesAnalysis;
        salesAnalysis.open ("salesAnalysis.txt");
        salesAnalysis << displayAllCars(cars) << endl;
        salesAnalysis << "Total Sales for the Company(RM): " << totalSales << endl;
```

The error is "no match for operator << in salesAnalysis"

Comment: `displayAllVehicles` or `displayAllCars` ? Notice that both return `void` so cannot be mixed with `<<`

Comment: Sorry I have made the changes. It's displayAllCars. May I know how do I fix this so that I can display the function into a text file ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ostream & displayAllCars(ostream & ostr, vector<Vehicle*>& cars)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++)
    {
        ostr << i+1 <<". ";
        cars[i]->display(ostr);
        ostr << endl;
    }
}

ofstream salesAnalysis("salesAnalysis.txt");
displayAllCars(salesAnalysis, cars);
salesAnalysis << "Total Sales for the Company(RM): " << totalSales << endl
```

Comment: I got an error when i tried this "no matching function for call to 'Vehicle::display(std::ostream&)"

If it's cars[i]->display(); it works but it only shows the index 'i'.

Comment: You have to adapt vehicle::display() method to accept ostream argument. Another option is to drop display() method and replace it with << operator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload an operator << :

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const vehicle &vc) {
    vc.display(os);
    return os;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const vector<vehicle*> &vc) {
    for(int i = 0; i < vc.size; ++i) {
        os << *vc[i] << " "; // after *vc[i] some separator or std::endl
    }
    return os;
}
```